# Android / iOS API access to Bluetooth heart-rate monitors

Tags: iphone, android, ios, embedded, bluetooth

I'm looking to write some Android or iOS applications to access a Bluetooth heart-rate monitor. There are currently some apps available like Android's "Heart Rate Monitor" that connect to heart-rate monitors like the [Zephyr HxM](http://www.zephyr-technology.com/consumer-hxm), so I know it can be done.

What is the programming API like? If I write an app, would it be able to connect to any heart-rate device? Or would I have to follow some application-layer protocol from the device manufacturer and read and process Bluetooth packets?

Comment: I think it really depends on the device manufacturer, whether they've made their protocol public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the bluetooth enabled Heart-rate monitors supports the SPP profile and you can use the Android Bluetooth SPP socket APIs to access the device.
The [Android chat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) example is a good application to modify to start with.

Comment: how to decode the bytes coming from the heart rate monitor?